# How can I apply the animation of an object to particles in the particle system and control the velocity?

Tags: animation, particles

I need to animate salt particles falling from a container and sticking to an object (collision object) when they fall.

I tried particle emission, but I can't able to control their speeds individually *(I want to make animation go from slow motion to normal speed)*.

I animated one salt crystal individually (not a particle emission object) as how I wanted it to fall.
Now can I apply that animation to particles in particle system?

How can I control the speeds of individual particles in particle emission?